# Spin-Polarized calculation in density functional theorem

Tags: density-functional-theory

I am a beginner in DFT calculations. I want to know what is spin-polarization and is it necessary to choose it always while doing DFT calculations ?

I do not understand what spin-polarization actually is. Please help..

Comment: check out this new materials modeling stack exchange https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: 3 months is long for no answer, Can you copy and paste into Materials SE?